# Sabre REST API equivalent to SOAP SabreCommandLLS

Tags: rest, sabre

Can anyone please tell me if Sabre has REST API equivalent to SOAP SabreCommandLLS Service with Action SabreCommandLLSRQ? If Sabre has developed the same, where I can find its documentation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there' s not a REST equivalent service.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what kind of transaction are you trying to execute using Sabrecommand ?
Just to remember, use of Sabrecommand it is do not considered a good practice, you should try to avoid use this kind of approach, you should use always services (REST/SOAP) instead of Sabrecommand.
Second of all, Sabrecommand is not supported by REST and the reason is obvious, is do not recommended to use Sabrecommand.